# How to count number of unique strings in two columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with two columns containing strings, like:

> **col1** --- **col2**
>   Ernst ---   Jim
>   Peter --- Ernst
>   Bill --- NaN
>   NaN --- Doug
>   Jim --- Jake

Now I want to create a new DataFrame with a list of unique strings in the first column and in the second column the number of occurrences of each string in the 2 original columns, like:

> **str** --- **occurences**
>   Ernst --- 2
>   Peter --- 1
>   Bill --- 1
>   Jim --- 2
>   Jake --- 1
>   Doug --- 1

How do I do that in the most efficient way? Thanks!

> 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First combine your original two columns into one:

```
In [127]: s = pd.concat([df.col1, df.col2], ignore_index=True)

In [128]: s
Out[128]: 
0    Ernst
1    Peter
2     Bill
3      NaN
4      Jim
5      Jim
6    Ernst
7      NaN
8     Doug
9     Jake
dtype: object
```

and then use `value_counts`:

```
In [129]: s.value_counts()
Out[129]: 
Ernst    2
Jim      2
Bill     1
Doug     1
Jake     1
Peter    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Alternatively, `df.unstack().value_counts()`.  (If there are more columns than just `col1` and `col2` in the frame, you'd want to select those first.)

Comment: Ohh that's nice too. `df.stack().value_counts()` gives the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do that way (assuming you taking the data from a file `your_file.txt` and you want to print out the result):

```
from collections import Counter;

separator = ' --- '
with open('your_file.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()  # here you got a list of elements corresponding to the lines
    people = separator.join(content).split(separator) # here you got a list of all elements
    people_count = Counter(people) # you got here a dict-like object with key=name value=count
    for name, val in people_count.iteritems():
        # print the column the way you want
        print '{name}{separator}{value}'.format(name=name, separator=separator, value=val)
```

The example use the [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object which allows you to efficiently count element from an iterable. the rest of the code is only string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1" : ["Ernst", "Peter","Bill",np.nan,"Jim"],
 "col2" : ["Jim","Ernst",np.nan,"Doug","Jake"]})
print df
df1 = df.groupby("col1")["col1"].count()
df2 = df.groupby("col2")["col2"].count()
print df1.add(df2,fill_value=0)
```